# Multiple read more (ellipses) on one page showing all and not each section individually

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have multiple lists of tags on a search results page, each one limited to show only two tags, if there are more I have added an ellipses (...) to show the hidden ones on click. It's working to an extent, but clicking on one opens all of the sections and instead of the specific one.

```
$('.categories-list').each(function (index, value) {
    $('.seymour').click(function () {
      $('.categories-list li:hidden').show();
      if ($('.categories-list li').length === $('.categories-list li:visible').length) {
        $('.seymour').hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

the list is being limited in css

```
.categories-list li:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}
```

here is the html that displays the list

```
<div class="search-teaser-issues">
    <ul class="categories-list">
       {% for category in categories_array %}
         <li class="category">{{ category }}</li>
       {% endfor %}
       <span class="category seymour"> . . . </span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would guess you need to change `$('.categories-list li:hidden')` to a selector relative to the `.seymour` which raised the click event. However, we can't show you what the code to do this would be without seeing the relevant HTML. Can you please edit the question to include it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated the question to include the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1):

So i figured out what i was doing wrong, and learned some important lessons along the way.

Assuming that jquery was smart enough to do what i wanted was wrong, learning how to use

`this` and `parent()` were essential

in the end this code worked, and kept the open feature siloed to the one i wanted.

```
$('.categories-list .seymour').click(function () {
  var par = $(this);
  var list = par.parent('ul');
  list.find('li:hidden').show();
});
```